# Log EF Core Exceptions to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to have a logging table in SQL where I log application events and I want to use Entity Framework Core to do so since it is used in the rest of the application. My problem is that if an error is thrown on entity frameworks SaveChanges() and I then want to add a Log entity for that exception to the same database and call SaveChanges(), the same exception is thrown again. Is it possible to use the same DBContext to log messages or do I need a separate DBContext? Is it possible to create a clean DBContext that can be used to log EF/SQL messages?

Comment: Use a clean context (unless you're sure about connection state when exception occurs) but do not do it by yourself. Logging has to be reliable and it may not be that easy. Your logging framework probably has a _writer_ specific for DB.

Comment: You'll need a separate DbContext. Any reason in particular you are rolling your own error logging, instead of using an existing error logging library like [StackExchange.Exceptional](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional) or [ELMAH](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah), or a general logging library like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)?